# Filtrar varias palabras de un array PHP

Tags: php, html

Buenas lo que estoy intentando es poder filtrar cierta cantidad de palabras provenientes de un array dinamico

```
$array=str_split($odon->odont,7);
```

primero tomo el array de forma dinámica y lo secciono de modo que me quede el array de esta forma Array ( [0] => operat [1] => exodon [2] => sellap [3] => corona [4] => l18_op [5] => r18_op [6] => b17_ex [7] => c16_ex [8] => c44_sp [9] => r43_sp [10] => c26_co

hasta aqui voy bien luego de eso me pongo a la tarea de filtrar

```
$matches = array_filter($array, function($var) use ($termToSearch) { return stristr($var, $termToSearch); });
if($matches) {
echo 'Se ha encontrado el termino "'.$termToSearch.'" en los siguientes campos:';
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<input type ="texto" class="text" value='.$match.' style="margin-left:43px;">';
   // echo '<div class=col-md-6>'.$match;
    echo '<div data-name="value" id="dienteindex" class="dientes col-md-2">
            <div id="t" class="arriba cuadro click" value="arr">
            <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check" id="tindex" hidden=""></div>
            <div id="l" class="cuadro izquierda click" value="izq">
            <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check" id="lindex" hidden=""></div>
            <div id="b" class="cuadro abajo click" value="aba">
            <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check" id="bindex" hidden=""></div>
            <div id="r" class="cuadro derecha click click" value="der">
            <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check" id="rindex" hidden=""></div>
            <div id="c" class="centro centros click" value="cen">
            <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check" id="cindexi" hidden=""></div>
            </div>';
    echo '</table>';
    }
}
} else {
echo 'El termino "'.$termToSearch.'" no se ha encontrado en el array.';
```

}

este filtro  me funciona perfecto me guarda en un input los resultados que contengan la palabra _op en ella el problema es que necesito no solo filtrar _op sino 9 términos mas y que al igual que el anterior todos se me muestren reflejados en el value de los input, pero cuando intento agregar los demas terminos de este modo

```
$termToSearch = '_op','_ex','_sp', '_re','_pr','_pp','_ca','_sa','_co','au';
```

me salta el siguiente error

syntax error, unexpected ',' de verdad e intentado de todas formas pero no se en que puedo estar mal les agradesco mucho la ayuda que puedan prestarme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un `Array` de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
$array = Array ('operat', 'exodon', 'sellap', 'corona', 'l18_op', 'r18_op', 'b17_ex', 'c16_ex', 'c44_sp', 'r43_sp', 'c26_co');
$termToSearch = Array('_op','_ex','_sp', '_re','_pr','_pp','_ca','_sa','_co','au');
$matches = array_filter($array, function($var) use ($termToSearch) { 
    $found = false;
    foreach ($termToSearch as $term) {
        if(stristr($var, $term)) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $found;
});
if($matches) {
echo 'Se han encontrado coincidencias en los siguientes campos:';
echo '<br>';
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<input type ="texto" class="text" value='.$match.' style="margin-left:43px;">';
   // echo '<div class=col-md-6>'.$match;
    echo '<div data-name="value" id="dienteindex" class="dientes col-md-2">
            <div id="t" class="arriba cuadro click" value="arr">
            <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check" id="tindex" hidden=""></div>
            <div id="l" class="cuadro izquierda click" value="izq">
            <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check" id="lindex" hidden=""></div>
            <div id="b" class="cuadro abajo click" value="aba">
            <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check" id="bindex" hidden=""></div>
            <div id="r" class="cuadro derecha click click" value="der">
            <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check" id="rindex" hidden=""></div>
            <div id="c" class="centro centros click" value="cen">
            <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check" id="cindexi" hidden=""></div>
            </div>';
    echo '</table>';
    }
} else {
echo 'Los terminos no se han encontrado en el array.';
}
?>
```